# Fitting a larger bike frame

Tags: bike-fit

I purchased a Lemond Zurich 2006 bike from CL. I am 5'7" with inseam of 29.5". The size of the bike was listed as 51 cm, but I later found that the size is 57 cm (suitable for 6'1"). I was able to raise the handle bar and adjust the saddle and feel ok riding the bike, though it feels odd and different from what I experience with my 52cm bike. I rode for 10 miles today mostly on flat road without issues. Are there a health hazard or any other issue I should be aware of ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make a larger bike fit a smaller person?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16352/is-it-possible-to-make-a-larger-bike-fit-a-smaller-person)

Answer (score 1):

That’s quite a bit too large.

The difference between a size 57 and size 51 frame is a ~4cm longer top tube and a ~6cm longer seat tube. *If* the stand-over height is sufficient (i.e. you can stand with both feet flat on the ground without hitting your crotch on the top tube) it might just be possible to do enough adjustments.

You can probably lower the saddle far enough and get the fore-aft adjustment right.

Adjusting reach is a bit more tricky. The bike probably comes with a 90mm or 100m stem. If you replace with a short 50mm stem (only costs a few bucks) it will look quite silly but should probably get the job done.

The 57cm frame has a much longer headtube which means your handlebars can’t go very low, so you’ll never be able to achieve a low, aerodynamically advantageous position on that bike. Not a problem if you want an upright position.

Handling and weight distribution will suffer, but probably not too badly.

A few other differences in frame sizes: Bikes with larger frames often also come with wider handlebars (e.g. 44cm instead of 40cm) and longer crankarms (e.g. 175mm instead of 170mm). Replacing those components will be fairly expensive.

Comment: I assume a significantly shorter stem will also tamper with the bike's handling characteristics on top of everything that's already off.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs. I have already reversed the direction of the stem and added a spacer to raise the handlebar. This has made the biggest difference. I have also tried adjusting the saddle forward, but it gets uncomfortable beyond a point. I will try reducing the stem to a 50mm and how it handles.

Comment: So you *raised* the handlebars? I’d kind of expect you to put it as low as possible because the larger framesize already raises it by ~5cm. Don’t use the fore-aft adjustment of the saddle to compensate for the long top tube, that’s not its purpose.

Comment: After riding for a few months now with a 60 mm stem I like the way it rides. It feels different but comfortable. I don't feel noticeable difference in handling due to shorter stem. I like the upright riding position. I have done several 20 mile rides and don't feel much difference between this and my regular bike